# Check if a list is sorted on Scheme

Tags: list, debugging, sorting, scheme

i'm trying to check whether the list is sorted or not. If it is sorted, then return True otherwise return False. However, this code always return True and I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
(define (ordered? lst)
    (cond (if (null? lst) #t)
          ((> (car(cdr(lst))) car(lst))
           (apply increasing? cdr(lst)))
          (else #f))
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's think about what your code is doing.

First of all get rid of the `if` it is unnecessary in the `cond` clause. Next you have some non-scheme function calling going on:

```
      ((> (car(cdr(lst))) car(lst))
```

Should be:

```
  ((> (car (cdr lst)) (car lst))
```

Now you don't usually use `apply` in this kind of way. Instead I would use recursion.

So this:

```
       (apply increasing? cdr(lst)))
```

Becomes:

```
    (ordered (cdr lst)))
```

Think about what this is doing, I am checking if the rest of the list is ordered and if at some where it is not, this expression will evaluate to false and the rest of the expression will too.

Next we want to check in the case it that this particular instance is not sorted so:

```
  (else #f))
```

Is fine.

All in all:

```
(define (ordered? lst)
      (cond ((null? lst) #t)
            ((eq? (length lst) 1) #t)
      ((> (car (cdr lst)) (car lst))
        (ordered? (cdr lst)))
      (else #f))
     )
```

Comment: this gives me error of unbound variable of ordered since i didn't define ordered. so i change to ordered? but i got another error that saying "car: wrong type of argument".

Comment: Oh yeah, you also have to worry about singleton lists... I updated the all in all.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `if` inside `cond`. The first line should be:

```
(cond ((null? lst) #t)
```

Your code was testing whether `if` is true. Since this is always true, that clause was processed and it returned `#t`.